# Python: Editing specific list indices from a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, namespaces

I'm trying to loop through a list in Python, make some changes to it, and then output a result. Here's the function:

```
def scramble_bytes(self, ref_key):
    """
    Uses ref_key as a reference to scramble self. 
    They must be equal-length lists of bytes
    """
    if len(self) != len(ref_key):
        return "Inputs to scramble_bytes must be equal length!"
    scrambles_needed = range(len(self))
    scramble_length = len(self)
    output = self
    for i in scrambles_needed:
        scramble_selector = int.from_bytes(ref_key[i], byteorder='big')
        scrambler_byte = int.from_bytes(output[(scramble_selector + i) % scramble_length], byteorder='big')
        scrambled_byte = int.from_bytes(output[i], byteorder='big')
        result_scramble = scrambler_byte ^ scrambled_byte
        output[i] = result_scramble.to_bytes(1, byteorder="big")
    return output
```

To clarify, `self` and `ref_key` are both lists of bytes- such as `[b'a', b'c', b'xb0']`

I know that it's not common practice to edit a list that's being looped through in Python, but in this case I need to do it, because the entire process needs to be reversible through another function that only gets `output` and `ref_key` as its inputs. If I append to a new list, the function will not be reversible.

I suspect that the problem has something to do with python namespaces- `output[i]` would create a new local variable in the `for` loop. If this is indeed the issue, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: make a copy of the list to be mutated in a loop.

Making a copy of the list to be processed will not make the function ireverisble. A mutated list is inherently a ``new list" (in the math sense).

Reversing the process should still be possible in a different function.

It is best for you to make a copy of the list being processed.

This code seem to be a method trying to modify its object directly. Is this what you really want? If that is the case look in to metaclasses.

Assuming you want to modify an attribute of an object, you can make an attribute self.original_ which represents the list to be scrambled, and just the scramble function. This way you do not need the unsrambe function as you can update the attributes as needed.